# Lodash - How to sum the length of array of array

Tags: lodash

I have an array of array

```
const myArrays = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // length = 4
    [ 1, 2], // length = 2
    [ 1, 2, 3], // length = 3
];
```

How I get the sum length of all children array?

```
const length = 4 + 2 + 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_.sumBy`

```js
const myArrays = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // length = 4
    [ 1, 2], // length = 2
    [ 1, 2, 3], // length = 3
];

 var length = _.sumBy(myArrays, 'length');
console.log("length =", length);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js'><</script>
```

Comment: The function passed to `sumBy` can be replaced with the property iteratee:`sumBy(myArrays, 'length')`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `_.forEach` or `_.reduce`

```js
const myArrays = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // length = 4
    [ 1, 2], // length = 2
    [ 1, 2, 3], // length = 3
];

var length = 0;

_.forEach(myArrays, (arr) => length += arr.length);

console.log('Sum of length of inner array using forEach : ', length);

length = _.reduce(myArrays, (len, arr) => { 
  len += arr.length;
  return len;
}, 0);

console.log('Sum of length of inner array using reduce : ', length);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js'><</script>
```